# Why do I get type error when the type is correct?

Tags: typescript

Html code:

```
<body>

<template id="hello">
    <div>Hellow world!</div>
</template>
<script src="x.js"></script>
</body>
```

Typescript code:

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "hello " + person
}

var user = "Jane"
var greetNode = document.createElement("p")
greetNode.innerHTML = greeter(user)
document.body.appendChild(greetNode)
var node = document.importNode(
    document.querySelector("#hello").firstChild, true
)
document.body.appendChild(node)
```

Error from chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'importNode' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Expected behavior is that the "hello world" div should be added to the html body.

The jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kindlychung/4o2fwwfb/

Any suggestions?

Comment: What result do you expect of document.body.appendChild(node) ?

Comment: See my edits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Content inside of `template` tag is not rendered, it is not actually in the document. The line `document.querySelector("#hello").firstChild` is returning `null`, hence the error.

In order to access template's inner HTML you can use its `content` attribute. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) you can read the following:

> There is also a content attribute, which is read-only and provides access to the template's contents.

So the code would be:

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "hello " + person
}

var user = "Jane"
var greetNode = document.createElement("p")
greetNode.innerHTML = greeter(user)
document.body.appendChild(greetNode)

var template = document.querySelector("#hello")
var div = template.content.querySelector("div")

var node = document.importNode(div, true)
document.body.appendChild(node)
```